# fping hosts in file and return down ips

Tags: bash, ping

I want to use fping to ping multiple ips contained in a file and output the failed ips into a file i.e.

hosts.txt

```
8.8.8.8
8.8.4.4
1.1.1.1
```

ping.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
HOSTS="/tmp/hosts.txt"
fping -q -c 2 < $HOSTS

if ip down 
echo ip > /tmp/down.log
fi
```

So I would like to end up with 1.1.1.1 in the down.log file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that parsing the data from fping is somewhat difficult. It allows the parsing of data for hosts that is alive but not dead. As a way round the issue and to allow for multiple host processing simultaneously with -f, all the hosts that are alive are placed in a variable called alive and then the hosts in the /tmp/hosts.txt file are looped through and grepped against the variable alive to decipher whether the host is alive or dead. A return code of 1 signifies that grep cannot find the host in alive and hence an addition to down.log.

```
alive=$(fping -c 1 -f ipsfile | awk -F: '{ print $1 }')
while read line
do 
    grep -q -o $line <<<$alive
    if [[ "$?" ==  "1" ]]
    then
           echo $line >> down.log
    fi
done < /tmp/hosts.txt
```

Comment: I need to use fping -c (value) which gives output of '1.1.1.1   : xmt/rcv/%loss = 1/0/100%' so need to grep/awk for 'loss'

Comment: OK, I've amended the solution

Comment: Seems like it's difficult to parse the output from fping easily and so I have change the solution again to use a loop

Comment: thank you that works much better, and finally before marking your answer how would i do it with fping -f hosts.txt as this ping all the ips in the file in parallel but still need the down.log to update an ip at a time.

Comment: Parsing the data for hosts that are unreachable is proving tricky!!! I have come up with a "workaround" and I have amended the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to get the result you want. Note however; i didn't use fping anywhere in my script. If the usage of fping is crucial to you then i might have missed the point entirely.

```
#!/bin/bash

HOSTS="/tmp/hosts.txt"

declare -i DELAY=$1 # Amount of time in seconds to wait for a packet
declare -i REPEAT=$2 # Amount of times to retry pinging upon failure

# Read HOSTS line by line
while read -r line; do
    c=0
    while [[ $c < $REPEAT ]]; do
        # If pinging an address does not return the word "0 received", we assume the ping has succeeded
        if [[ -z $(ping -q -c $REPEAT -W $DELAY $line | grep "0 received") ]]; then 
            echo "Attempt[$(( c + 1))] $line : Success"
            break;
        fi

        echo "Attempt[$(( c + 1))] $line : Failed"

        (( c++ ))
    done

    # If we failed the pinging of an address equal to the REPEAT count, we assume address is down  
    if [[ $c == $REPEAT ]]; then 
        echo "$line : Failed" >> /tmp/down.log # Log the failed address
    fi

done < $HOSTS
```

Usage: ./script [delay] [repeatCount] -- 'delay' is the total amount of seconds we wait for a response from a ping, 'repeatCount' is how many times we retry pinging upon failure before deciding the address is down.

Here we are reading the `/tmp/hosts.txt` line by line and evaluating each adress using `ping`. If pinging an address succeeds, we move on to the next one. If an address fails, we try again for as many times as the user has specified. If the address fails all of the pings, we log it in our `/tmp/down.log`.

The conditions for checking whether a ping failed/succeeded may not be accurate for your use-cases, so maybe you will have to edit that. Still, i hope this gets the general idea across.

Comment: Thats for that but i specifically need fping.